# Bind event to dojo dialog dynamic content

Tags: dojo, esri

I am coding for Arcgis with Dojo. Badly stuck at a point. I have a dojo dialog which has list generated with Javascript. I am not able to bind 'data-dojo-attach-event'. The dialog is working fine but the click event is not working. 
Thanks!

```
var wireHtml = '<table class="table table-striped"><tbody>';
  for (let i = 0; i < wiresList.length; i++) {
    if(wiresList[i].attributes.conduit_id === Number(conduitId)){
        wireHtml += '<tr><td>' + wiresList[i].attributes.name + ' <span class="badge pull-right" data-dojo-attach-event="click:wireDetail">detail</span></td></tr>';
    }
  }
  wireHtml += '</tbody></table>';
  wiresDialog.containerNode.innerHTML = wireHtml;
  wiresDialog.show();
```

Comment: Have you tried using onClick instead of click?

Comment: This is what I did. Defined a function on top that return the a function.

var wireDetail = (values) => {
  return function () {
        console.log('wireDetail');
        var formClass = 'form-wire';
        var wireInputs = selectAll('.' + formClass + ' input, .' + formClass + ' select, .' + formClass + ' textarea');
        if(values){
          setFormValues(values, formClass);
        }
        dijit.byId('myDialog').show();
    };
};